# Overriding the ASP.NET Membership provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to understand the point of inheriting the Membership provider in a custom class and overriding it to implement your own custom provider.

What's the benefit of this when the Membership provider sucks in the first place!

I'm trying to figure out why people are inheriting from the provider when you can just roll your own.  You're gonna have to create the logic anyway even if you override the membership provider classes.  Plus if I'm gonna create my own provider I'm not necessarily going to want to model my method signatures or # of methods by this provider if I don't like it in the first place.

Comment: It may not meet your needs, but that doesn't mean it sucks.  It works perfectly well for a majority of uses.

Comment: ok most shops that are serious do not like it.  Especial serious ecommerce shops.

Comment: How do you know?  I've worked at 3 ecommerce shops, all of them use the Membership API.  One of them is in the top 100 ecommerce sites list.

Comment: because I said I don't like the GUIDs, the table structure, etc, so why bother even inheriting from it.  It's just hokey, that's how I know, I've looked at it.  It's not extensible in that it ties you to SQL Server first off.  And like I said I hate Guids.

Comment: You really have NOT looked at it, because if you had you would know you are completely wrong.  Membership API does *NOT* tie you to guids, nor does it tie you to SQL Server.  ASP.NET even ships a membership provider for ActiveDirectory, and there are providers for MySQL, Oracle and others.  I suggest you actually know what you're talking about before you insist you do.

Comment: I have looked at it...it's a joke.  I do not like the schema with the membership provider.

Comment: The Membership API does not define a schema.  Are you getting it yet?  The API has nothing to do with ANY of your complaints.  You don't like the SqlMembershipProvider.  That's fine.  So write a custom provider that has the schema you want and uses the key type you want.  Accesses the database you want.  Using the technology you want.  It's extermely flexible.  The only "joke" here is the fact you insist you know what you're talking about.  You don't, and you haven't actually looked any further than a cursory glance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the built-in Membership provider sucks (I've had to re-write it myself, for use with large-scale sites where performance and scalability are concerns).

The advantage of using it is that it's easy, reasonably well documented, with lots of examples on the web.

The point of inheriting from the standard implementation is that makes it easy to just change the way a few things work. If you're going to re-write it from scratch, then I would skip the inheritance (which is what I've done).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for, someone who understands that it sucks...where you don't need to have a long discussion as to WHY..because if you look at it under the covers it's completely obvious.

Comment: Rick, just curious how you generally went about coding your own.  What was the general architecture if I may ask in sum?

Comment: There's a fair amount to it: full async I/O support, offloaded but integrated email verification and click-back for account activation, detailed user info capture for fraud detection and prevention, encrypted ticket cookies, minimized/optimized DB accesses, robust bot-resistant registration, scalable DB schema using stored procedures, extra security around password storage and handling, steps to make it difficult to steal and use ticket cookies -- and so on. I'm thinking about offering this version as a product soon, included as part of a sample website that I've built for my book.

Comment: Architecture: Member class to create, activate and logon users. Ticket class to create, validate and manage the cookie that indicates a user has logged-on. DAL with async ADO.NET for data access. Identity:IIdentity class to access ID info from the Ticket. DB tables collected in a single schema. There's a special SQL identity needed to access Membership tables & SPs. Lots of validation at multiple levels for registration. A Windows Service handles sending confirmation emails, directly to the final SMTP server, not through an intermediary. HttpModule to check Ticket and create a principal. Etc.

Comment: What did you find about the membership provider outside what I stated that you did not like?

Comment: It's a long list. A few that come to mind: synchronous DB access only, using web server-side DateTime (skew issues with multiple servers), the whole "application ID" implementation; numerous DB schema issues; inefficient stored procedures; multiple security concerns; buggy transaction boundaries in some stored procedures; no change auditing (still working on that one myself); supporting banned users is usually done with a hack, if at all; lack of fully integrated support with groups/roles, non-scalable email handling with no real feedback; lacking security and other features in ticket cookies.

Answer (score 2):

You override the membership provider so that you can use the Membership API with it.  This is useful for many purposes.  For instance, if you're trying to integrate many third party web forums into your app, they require using the Membership API.

I fail to understand what people find so lacking in the membership API.  Membership is not about having your users first and last names, or addresses or other information.  It's strictly about validating login credentials, and providing role based security.  That's it.

When you want to add other fields, you do so in your own tables, and make your membership ProviderUserKey a lookup value in your tables.

Comment: Yea thanks. I just don't want to use the membership tables and GUIDs.  I don't like the structure of the membership provider.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict - You don't have to use the membership tables, or Guids.  Membership lets you use anything you want for a key.

Comment: Yes but then why inherit from it in that case if you're not using any of it is my question....

Comment: @CoffeeAddict - You are still using it, you're just the methods with your own implementation.  You are still using the Membership API.  ProviderUserKey is a defined as an object, so you can you use any type you like for it.

Comment: thanks, this helps..but again ProviderUserKey is based on GUID.  I do not want to use GUIDs, I want to use integer Identity.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict - and again, that's not true.  It's only a Guid if you use the SqlMembershipProvider.  If you have a custom provider, you can specify whatever type you want.  All my providers use an int, as an example.  ProviderUserKey is whatever type the provider specifies, which is why the API defines it as an object.

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage is that the membership provider just works with all the "out of the box" asp.net features. Things like Forms Authentication, SiteMapProviders etc are designed to work well with the asp.net membership provider so often it's not so much the provider itself that is the key, it's the things that depend on the provider that make it worth while re-implementing.

Having said that, this doesn't mean that the membership provider will be a suitable fit for your situation, as you may not be using any of the components that are dependent on it, in which case, it doesn't make much sense to implement it and therefore you would be much better off writing your own membership model that does suit your needs.

Comment: can you explain more about the things that depend on the provider and why you rolled your own provider?  We just don't want to use the membership tables and Guids